# logging array item by index returning undefiened

Tags: javascript

I was making a program that recoreded every keypress and pushed it to an array and it works fine. The problem is when I try to access the first element of the array and log it, it prints undefined. But the whole array logs fine.Why is it printing undefiened? I have added both console log of the array and the array item in my code and have commented besides them to indicate. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** turn out what doesn't work is accessing the last item. I have updated the code above

```js
var cacheW = []
var cacheA = []
var cacheD = []
var cacheS = []

// (B1) CAPTURE KEY STROKES
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
  if (evt.key == "w") {
    cacheW.push('w');
    //console.log("this: " + evt.key)
  } else if (evt.key == "a") {
    cacheA.push('a');
    //console.log("this: " + evt.key)
  } else if (evt.key == "d") {
    cacheD.push('d');
    //console.log("this: " + evt.key)
  } else if (evt.key == "s") {
    cacheS.push('s');
    //console.log("this: " + evt.key)
  }

});


window.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
  if (evt.key == "w") {
    cacheW.push("!w");
    //console.log("this: " + evt.key + " removed")
  } else if (evt.key == "a") {
    cacheA.push("!a");
    //console.log("this: " + evt.key + " removed")
  } else if (evt.key == "d") {
    cacheD.push("!d");
    //console.log("this: " + evt.key + " removed")
  } else if (evt.key == "s") {
    cacheS.push("!s");
    //console.log("this: " + evt.key + " removed")
  }

});

//works
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(cacheW) //logs an array 
}, 50)

//doesn't work
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(cacheW[-1]) //logs undefined, should have logged the last element
}, 50)
```

Comment: its showed undefine becuase `cacheW[0]` , the index 0 is not exist in the array

Comment: @AlexYu but I just logged the whole array above ana it clearly has a length  > 1 so index 0 should exist

Comment: @seriously `[]` is an empty array. It has length 0, not 1. As soon as you have pressed a key at least once, both your interval functions will print the array and first item respectively

Comment: @knittl turn out what doesn't work is accessing the last item. I have updated the code above

Comment: `cacheW[-1]` doesnt' do what you think it does.  Javascript is different from Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript access array items by their index. `-1` is an invalid index. To access the last item, use `arr[arr.length - 1]`.

Other languages such as python offer syntactic sugar to access items from the end of an array. JavaScript does not have such syntactic sugar. The closest which you can get is to write `arr.slice(-1)[0]`, but this will create a temporary single-item array and then access the first item of this array.

In fact `-1` is a *property*, not a valid index. Property names are first stringified, then added to the object (every array is an object):

```
a = [];
a[-1] = 42;
console.log(a); // [], array itself is still empty
console.log(a[-1]); // 42, property -1 on the object has value assigned
console.log(a['-1']); // 42, object property keys are always converted to string first
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
//doesn't work
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(cacheW[0])//logs undefined, should have logged the first element
}, 50)
```

This:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (cacheW.length > 0) {
      console.log(cacheW[0]);
  } else {
      console.log("<empty>");
  }
}, 50);
```

**Update**
If you want to print the last item:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (cacheW.length > 0) {
      console.log(cacheW[cacheW.length-1]);
  } else {
      console.log("<empty>");
  }
}, 50);
```

Comment: turn out what doesn't work is accessing the last item. I have updated the code above

Comment: @seriously - What do you think `cacheW[-1]` does?  Hint: Javascript isn't Python.

Comment: was treating it like python you are right. Thanks